# How to set up postfix to accept mail for erroneously spelled domain?

Tags: postfix

Let's say I have an email address, bob@mystudio.com, with a working SMTP server. I want to set up my server and DNS so that if they mistakenly email bob@mystudios.com, it still gets there.

I have the MX record set up so the MX for mystudios.com is mystudio.com, but unfortunately email bounces with "Relay access denied."

How do I configure postfix to accept mail from mystudios.com?

I should also mention that mystudio.com accepts mail for many different domains, so I have a setup where mysql tables are used to verify domains/aliases/mailboxes. E.g.:

**main.cf:**

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
```

More details:

If I add mystudios.com to the `domain` mysql table, I get a different error now:

```
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
```

But I don't want to have to set up the exact same aliases that exist on mystudio.com. I just want anything sent to mystudios.com to redirect to mystudio.com.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work outside  your network unless you register the misspelled domains (and point the MX records to your server), or you are running the DNS server for your clients (and that would be an ugly ugly hack).

If you are willing to register the misspelled domains, just add the domain to your `virtual_domains` or `mydestination` configuration options, there is no shortage of information about that available.

Comment: Like I said, I have an MX record set up with mystudios.com to point to mystudio.com. Both domains are registered. It's all set up properly on the DNS side, it's just that postfix won't take mail for the misspelled domain.

Comment: You can also use `virtual_alias_domains` if you just want the email to be directed to users on your system.. as I see you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "mystudios.com" to the:

```
mydestination = ...
```

of /etc/postifx/main.cf

Also Postfix Documentation: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination

Comment: I'm not using a basic config though. mystudio.com accepts mail for several different domains, so I have a mysql setup where domains, mailboxes, and aliases are queried from mysql tables.

Comment: Well then, short of the ole' service postfix restart.. I'll bow out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The solution was to just go into Postfix Admin, add the misspelled domain, and then make it an alias of mystudio.com, then reload the postfix server.